# Cordova iOS app closing shows the default cordova app icon for a fraction of a second and then shows the custom app icon

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, phonegap, appicon

I am working with cordova phonegap iOS app. The app icon and splashscreen works perfect. But when i close the app, it shows the default cordova icon for a fraction of a second. Then it shows the custom app icon i set. Can you help me with a solution? Thanks in advance